# Introduce a sentence with "leveraging"

Tags: word-choice

Does this sentence make sense:

Leveraging lessons learned from the previous project, collaborating with an industry association and supplier to address the financial and technical challenges of this initiative will increase the likelihood of implementation.

Comment: What do you think is wrong with it?

Comment: Other than the fact that it's generally meaningless gobbledygook, I see nothing wrong.

Comment: From "Leveraging" to the comma can be understood as a "sentence adverb". The comma does not indicate a list.

Comment: Thanks for your help. keshlam, I thought there was a disconnect between the introductory phase ("Leveraging" to the comma) and the rest of the sentence. I thought it might be better to say: "Based on lessons learned from the previous project, ..."

Comment: But "Based on lessons learned..." would not fit in with the management-speak gobbledygook nearly as well as "Leveraging ..." does.

Comment: Does it mean something like this: We learned from our last project that we can increase our chances of success by collaborating with an industry association and a supplier?

Answer (score 2):

The generic version of your question is

> Beginning a sentence with a present participle or gerund.

Sure you can.

- Texting while driving is an extremely dangerous habit.
- Texting his friends while driving, he would be drinking latte at the same time.
- Painting houses is her favourite past time.
- Buying a house without a broker, she would save quite a sum of money from an unnecessary economic pestilence.
- Leveraging undervalued stocks and assets was Warren Buffett's path to success.
- Leveraging an undervalued stock, he intends to nurse it back to health.
- Being a fool does not absolve your responsibilities.
- Being a fool, he dunked his life savings into gambling on that one horse.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying the question and providing a very clear answer.